# PYTHON - List: Line 4 out of range

Tags: python

I wonder why line 4 shows an error "list index out of range"?

Furthermore, if I change line 4 to "new_list = new_list + i", it will show an output of '23'. I wonder is that possible because new_list is an int and i is list, can they concatenate together?

```
def ele(num_list):
    new_list = 0
    for i in num_list:
        new_list = new_list + int(num_list[i]) #list index out of range

    return new_list

def main():
    print(ele([1, 5, 17]))

main()
```

If I run the modified code below it give me an output of:

```
5
5
5
0
```

How could the 0 get printed because there are only 3 element in the list [1, 5, 17]?

```
def ele(num_list):
    new_list = 0
    for i in num_list:
        #new_list = new_list + int(num_list[i]) 
        print(num_list[1])

    return new_list

def main():
    print(ele([1, 5, 17]))

main()
```

Comment: should be new_list = new_list + int(i) ？

Comment: regarding the new, edited code -- you're printing `num_list[1]` -- the element at the 1st index of the list (you're using the number 1 instead of the letter i). The element at the 1st element is 5. You then return the variable `new_list`, which is the number 0, and proceed to print that out in your `main` function, which explains why the last line of output is 0 even though the length of your list is 3.

Comment: Isn't `ele` just `sum `? Why is an integer named `new_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` will give `i` values `1`, then `5`, then `17`. `num_list[1]` is fine, but `num_list[5]` is not (and neither would `num_list[17]` be). You probably want just `int(i)` and not `int(num_list[i])`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited with a new question regarding the output: 5 5 5 0. I wonder how would the 0 be printed? Thanks

Comment: Michael0x2a explains it well in a comment to your question.

Answer (score 3):

`i` isn't the index of the list, it's the element inside the list.

If I do:

```
arr = [1, 40, 2, 3]
for i in arr:
    print arr[i]
```

...I'm actually telling Python to do:

```
print arr[1]
print arr[40]
print arr[2]
print arr[3]
```

As you can see, it's easy for the value of 'i' to be out of range depending on what's inside the list.

To fix this, you can use the item directly:

```
for i in arr:
    print i
```

Or use `range`:

```
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    print arr[i]
```

Or use `enumerate` to the the value and the index simultaneously:

```
for index, value in enumerate(arr):
    print arr[index]
    print value
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited with a new question regarding the output: 5 5 5 0. I wonder how would the 0 be printed? Thanks

Comment: @dfefef -- I left a comment under your original question explaining why this occurs.